# Chrome re sizes pictures in css. Ie does not.(idk about ff)

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, resize

My code is below. The Hyperlink is there so that if you click on the picture it takes you to a different page but that page is not apart of my question. What i'm trying to do is use css to re-size an image according to the height of your web browser. In google chrome it works, but not in ie and idk about firefox. If someone could tell me what was wrong and rewrite my code in a way that would make it work for all browsers it would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<style>
.size{height:100%;}
.test{width:auto;height:100%;}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div class="size">
<a href="test2.html"><img class="test" src="test.jpg" border="0"></a> 
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in a container and then set the css as follows

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    a.container { 
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
    }
    a#image1 {
        background: url(YOURIMAGE.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="container" id="image1" href="#"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can ID each a tag that you want to have as a link and create a reference in css for it. This will not make the entire image fill the page and also be a link.